# Fetching data from multiple tables in Django

Tags: django

How to perform a join query? I want to fire query which act like:

```
select s.nm,s1.sub from Student s,Subject s1
```

Here I show what I tried in Django but doesn't work:

My model.py file is

```
    from django.db import models    
    class Student(models.Model):
        sid = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
        nm = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
        id = models.ForeignKey('Subject', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id', blank=True, null=True)

        class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'student'


    class Subject(models.Model):
        id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
        sub = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

        class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'subject'
```

view.py

```
    from django.http.response import HttpResponse
    from django.core import serializers
    from App.models import Student, Subject
    # Create your views here.
    def fun(request):
      #  obj1=Subject.objects.all()
        obj=Student.objects.filter(Subject.objects.all()).all()
        js=serializers.serialize("json",obj)
        return HttpResponse(js)
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Please do not add `fdhgjdfhjchnb ]ghnfghnghnghngf dhg hnfghnfghngfh` nonsense at the end of questions. The minimum length filter kicked in because a good deal of your paragraph text was formatted as code. That has now been repaired, but we'd prefer it if repair was not necessary.

Comment: Ok Thank you sir..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) attribute in model, and you can access the object this way.

models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    sid = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    nm = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    subject = models.ForeignKey("Subject", related_name="student", blank=True, null=True)

class Subject(models.Model):
    sub = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

```
from App.models import Student, Subject
def myFunc():
    students = Student.objects.all()
    for student in students:
        subj = student.subject.sub

def myFunc2():
    subjects = Subject.objects.all()
    for subject in subjects:
        student_name = subject.student.nm
```

Comment: How could I insert Subject value in Student table, because we give reference to whole table?and if we are inserting values of other table(Subject) while insert into Student table so what's the meaning of separating both table?

Answer (score 0):

As already defined in your models, try this:

```
from App.models import Student, Subject 

def fun(request):
    subjects=Subject.objects.all()
    obj=Student.objects.filter(id__in=subjects)
    js=serializers.serialize("json",obj)
    return HttpResponse(js)
```

Comment: How is this "fun" accessed via URL? Howz mapping done?