# getting value from Mysql and passing to Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I connected my database to django. I want to enable user (teacher) insert the name of  a student and get test results on certain subjects.

I run `python3 manage.py inspectdb` and inserted it into `models.py`

```
class Profilez(models.Model):
    student = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    schgroup = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'profilez'


class Schoolz(models.Model):
    profilez_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    lit = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    math = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'schoolz'
```

in `forms.py` i put:

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    SUB = (
        ('lit', 'lit'),
        ('math', 'math')

    )
    student = forms.CharField(max_length=150, label='', widget=forms.TextInput)


    class Meta:
        model = Schoolz
        fields = ('student',)
```

in `views.py`:

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = StudentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form1 = form.save(commit=True)
            name = form1.student

            ab=schoolz.objects.all()


            context={
            'name':name,
            }
            return render(request, 'book/analysis.html', context)

    else:
        form = StudentForm()
        return render(request, 'book/search.html', {'form': form})
```

Can you please help me to understand what i am doing wrong and how to get value for certain subject for exmaple math subject.

I would appreciate help and guidance to undertand and execute it. I am struggling a month.

Comment: 1) your view is not correct. it's not doing anything. 2) where are you saving marks of students? can you show the models.

Comment: the views does show and print the students name. But my goal is to get student's name and requests from data base to find it and based on it to get the student's math grade. It is located in my profile table in MySql

Comment: How can I make views to show the requested information form the database? I would appreciate your help

Comment: class Prof is my model to link to database. Am I ding it wrong ? It is in models.py

Comment: **@Nina**, You have two models but there exist no relationship. Without foreign key--you are trying to fetch data where you need to use two different table! Have you looked on the foreign key issue in your two models?

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean in your view you are not getting data as you wanted. sorry I don't understand what "Prof is my model to like to database" means. What are you saving in this model.

Comment: @sandeep sorry I corrected the error, I mean class Prof is my model that I try to get data form MySql. This is what I was told to do.

Comment: @sandeep views.py do get data of students but does not do anything further

Comment: as @IqbalHussain said, models are not connected. If you want scores of student, you need a table (model) related to Student model.

Comment: @sandeep can you please show some example?

Comment: @IqbalHussain what do you mean two different tables?

Comment: **@Nina**, do not worries :) You are here and your problem will be resolved! Look,  you want to get the grade with respect to student name for  a particular subject. So definitely you are maintaining two different tables. one for student info and other for student id with subject and grade. If this goes with your model than you have to have the relationship via foreign key or by related name. You may look this. may be related to your requirements. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48596388/fetching-data-from-multiple-tables-in-django#2%20Answers

Comment: Can I write a new to model to show example?

Comment: @IqbalHussain how can i link them? as in my case i require user (teachers) to insert student name and then the program should go to MySql and find student by its ids and then go to specific subject and extract grade for specific subject(Math). The example you sent looks lke my request however i can join table in MySql - my problem is how to link MySql and Django. Woudl appreciate any help to understand this. Thank you that you area trying to help

Comment: @sandeep Yes please that will be great.

Comment: If you want to link mysql to django, you need to specify DB name in settings.py in database dictionary. Now run "manage.py inspectdb" you will get all tables in DB. add table in models.py. and makemigrations and migrate.

Comment: if you show result of "manage.py inspectdb" after linking, we can help easily.

Comment: @sandeep please see the above code of of "manage.py inspectdb" I inserted as you told.

Answer (score 0):

@**Nina**,

Please look on the relationship> it's general idea for the Student & Gradesheet model

```
class Student(models.Model):

      std_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.std_name


class Gradesheet(models.Model):

      student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      sub = models.CharField(max_length=50)
      grade = models.CharField(max_length=50)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.student.std_name
```

So if you need to search for a student grade for particular subject:

```
      std_info = Student.objects.get(std_name='Nina')
```

Then you will get a Student Class instance for Nina.

Now fetch the data by relationship:

```
     std_grade =  std_info.gradesheet_set.filter(sub='math')
```

You will get QuerySet. Then just :

```
std_grade[0].grade
```

You will get your student's grade for particular subject. Look its a model relationship. So you may use other filtering options also to get your desired result.

According to your given model:

Instead of the **profile_id** you should use the **Profile** object which will help you to take the control through django ORM.

```
  class Profile(models.Model):
        student_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        student_surname = models.CharField(max_length=255)

        class Meta:
           managed = False
           db_table = 'profile'



 class Class10(models.Model):
       #profile_id = models.IntegerField()
       profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='profile')
       math = models.IntegerField()
       literature = models.IntegerField()
       biology = models.IntegerField()

       class Meta:
          managed = False
          db_table = 'class_10'
```

So your query can be build by:

```
     std_profile = Profile.objects.get(student_name='SomeoneName')
```

Now turn it for get the grade. **Result would be**:

```
     math_grade = std_profile.profile.math
     biology_grade = std_profile.profile.biology
     literature_grade = std_profile.profile.literature
     average_grade = ((math_grade + biology_grade + literature_grade)/3)
```

Here, your model relationship:Profile to Class10 is **OneToOne**

Comment: het thank you . I am looking for both answers so it takes time as I am new. I will come back to you soon with questions while I am testing your code

Comment: @Nina, your model relationship is OneToOne. Please have a look on the updated code.

Comment: @Nina, i can't understand where you got stuck. have you tried the code in the console. Sometime console is straightforward to debug the issue. If it works in console then ofcourse it will work in view file.I have checked my code at my end  and it works pretty well without any error. To get name:  **student_name = form.cleaned_data.get('student_name')**

Comment: @Nina, OneToOne based on ORM. it does not care does DB support it or not . Here every table represent as a model. And we are creating relationship based on the model. We are working in object layer.

Comment: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'OneToOne' . What is worng ?

Comment: @Nina, Please have a look on the updated code. would be : OneToOneField  sorry for that.

Comment: name = form.student_name
std_profile = Profile.objects.get(student_name=name)
math_grade = std_profile.profile.math

Comment: instead of  std_profile = Profile.objects.get(student_name='SomeoneName')  'SomeoneName i put name which is taken by form form a user. This way the code doe snot work and says get() returned more than one Profile -- it returned 11!

Comment: @Nina, you have more than one record by using the same name.

Comment: yes i see from data it fills my database with input queries. How to ban such case?

Comment: @Nina, instead of get() use filter here. So updated code: **std_profile = Profile.objects.filter(student_name='SomeoneName')**

Comment: 1)it still add input data in database 2) i again get error this time : QuerySet' object has no attribute 'profile'

Comment: @Nina, Have you added related_name='profile' ?                       **profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='profile')**

Comment: our codes differ i guess that is why it does not work,

Comment: @ **Nina** , How it differs? You models structure is following OneToOneField relationship. That's why you are using the syntax to fetch data from other table. I think you may edit your code here up to now what you did so far.

Comment: I am using the above structure i put which works i ony cannot get the values for certain subjects. But when i changed to your code it is not even displaying the input and i guess becuase i am mixing my code with your i am messing and missing smth. It is hard for me to figure out as i am new in Django

Answer (score 0):

### Notes

1. Add a field in Profile that should be unique for each student. Currently I am assuming name and surname combination will be unique.
2. If you use ajax, you can get score without refresh. Current way I have used is not very good.
3. You don't have to write models if you already have in DB. You can remove your models. add already present models in models.py and makemigrations and migrate.

Add a ForiegnKey field in Class10

```
class Class10(models.Model):
    profile_id = models.IntegerField()
    math = models.IntegerField()
    literature = models.IntegerField()
    biology = models.IntegerField()
    student = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='stud_name') # add this in model

    class Meta:
        managed = False  # make this True otherwise makemigrations won't get the changes.
        db_table = 'class_10'


class Profile(models.Model):
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    student_surname = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'profile'
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = StudentlForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form_1 = form.save(commit=False)
            name = form_1.student_name
            surname = form_1.student_surname
            subject = form_1.subject
            fil = Q(student__student_name=name) & Q(student__student_surname=surname)
            student_1 = StudentScore.objects.filter(fil).values()
            score = student_1[0][subject]  # answer

            context={
            'score':score
            }
            return render(request, 'school/analysis.html', context)

    else:
        form = StudentlForm()
        return render(request, 'school/search.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    SUB = (
        ('math', 'math'),
        ('literature', 'literature'),
        ('biology', 'biology')
    )
    student_name = forms.CharField(max_length=150, label='', widget=forms.TextInput)
    student_surname = forms.CharField(max_length=150, label='', widget=forms.TextInput)
    subject = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=SUB))

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('student_name', 'student_surname', 'subject')
```

Comment: I have not used validation, so in this answer teacher have to enter correct name without spelling error. I will recommend make student name a select box with search option.

Comment: @Nina, sorry I forgot commas.

Comment: @Nina, I have edited related_name in Class10 model student field to "stud_name". earlier it was "student_name" which was clashing student_name in Profile model.

Comment: may be you typed incorrect spelling. 2) you can remove surname. Just do it in models and migrate. Do remember to change all instances in views and form.

Comment: Also please check data is available for student you are searching.

Comment: Hey StudentScore is not defined, so the code is not working?Can you please have a look?

Comment: and it does not return any value as it says : get() returned more than one Profile -- it returned 4!

Comment: Would appreciate if you could help to udnersad the issue

Comment: when you use get() and it finds more than 1 values, it returns this error.

Comment: replace StudentScore  with Class10. I typed incorrectly.

Comment: Hey could you please help me with it. database was deleted and could not apply what you said. I created teh new one and followed the steps you explained however it does not work. Would you be able to assist me ?

Comment: @Nina, are you creating table directly in MySQL database (by workbench or phpmyadmin) or through the django model?

Comment: I am directly creating  in MySQL database.

Comment: I have update above what i did so far. Please have a look in my question above . I do not know what is the porblem.

Comment: @Nina, 1) You should not do this. It will be difficult for you. Everytime create/update table in DB and get code by inspectdb then adding in model. You should write models and after makemigrations + migrate table will be applied in MySQL DB. 2) For current problem, I can write a code to help you. I think you have asked a new question. Is it you?

Comment: yes it is my question. I would be thankful for your help. I agree with your 1 statement. Can you plase show an example of what should be right to do as you explained in your  statement 1 ?  i want to learn right way and be efficnet in the future. I will apreciate your help.

Comment: It may take time. Please check after 1:30 hrs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207351/discussion-between-sandeep-and-nina).